# How to prove this inequation in Fourier Analysis?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

$|e^{2\pi i (x+h)\xi} - e^{2\pi i (x)\xi}| \leq 2sin(\pi |h\xi|)$
Original inequation is
$\int \hat{f(\xi)}(e^{2\pi i (x+h)\xi} - e^{2\pi i (x)\xi})d\xi \leq \int |\hat{f(\xi)}|2sin(\pi |h\xi|)d\xi$
Thank you very much!

Comment: The LHS of the inequation is not necesseraly a real number. There's a mistake in the statement.

Comment: sorry for missing the absolute value sign

Comment: Alright that's good. Did you try factorizing by $e^{2\pi i x\xi}$? Notice that its module is $1$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well
$$
e^{2\pi i (x+h)\xi} - e^{2\pi i x \xi} = e^{2\pi i x \xi}(e^{2\pi i h \xi} - 1)
$$
So the absolute value of the left-hand side is
$$
|e^{2\pi i h \xi} - 1|...
$$
can you go from here (I was going to just write full answer but better respect the fact that Scientifica was giving hints)

Comment: Got it. It's quite easy. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you T_M :) But yeah in general I think it's better to give hints if these hints make the problem easier.

Comment: @zhm1995 Since you found this answer useful, don't forget to upvote it and mark it as accepted as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).